# Is there a Java equivalent of Twitter's Ostrich library?

Tags: java, ostrich

The ostrich project from Twitter seems to be a good fit for my use case where I would like to track lot of JVM based statistics plus some custom statistics.

https://github.com/twitter/ostrich/

However, my code base is pure Java + Spring 3.0, rather than Scala, so can I use Ostrich for my case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have used [Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/). It is very similar to Ostrich with support for gauges, counters, meters, histograms, and timers; As well a a mechanism to monitor the health check of your services.

You can get the report over JMX, or HTTP as well as reporting backends like Ganglia and Graphite.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this library. This is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

**The combination of MBeans, JMX, and the JConsole application provide this natively for both local as well as remote JVMs.**

The javax.management package ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html ) extensions support this : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html.

**The JMX+JConsole monitoring paradigm is native in your JVM, and increasingly easy to implement in java SE 1.6 on.**

> The Java virtual machine (Java VM ) has built-in instrumentation that
>   enables you to monitor and manage it using the Java Management
>   Extensions (JMX) technology. 
>     From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevs

**Details**

The standard way monitor any JVM (client, server, local, or remote) is using JConsole : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html.  You can have multiple JConsole clients open at once, monitoring different instances.

1) You first launch your JVM services with this argument :

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=portNum
```

2) Then , on your remote client (the one you want to do the monitoring) , you can start monitoring this JVM

```
jconsole hostName:portNum
```

**For integrating JVM Analytics over different servers**

1) Try the Clearstone app : I haven't used it, but screenshots appear to support the type of distributed envirnoment that you seem to have :

http://www.evidentsoftware.com/products/clearstone-for-java/

> ClearStone for Java includes an out-of-the-box collector that delivers metrics via JMX. The ClearStone server can collect and correlate information from any Java MBean.

**Finally, for another comparison of ostrich and jconsole : **

[Remote Probing of Scala/Java Application in Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577369/remote-probing-of-scala-java-application-in-runtime)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ostrich integrated with [Heapster](https://github.com/mariusaeriksen/heapster).

> **Heapster**
>
> Heapster provides an agent library to do heap profiling for JVM
> processes with output compatible with Google perftools. The goal of
> Heapster is to be able to do meaningful (sampled) heap profiling in a
> production setting.
>
> **Ostrich integration**
>
> If you use Ostrich, and run your program with heapster, you can
> generate runtime heap profiles like so:
>
> $ curl 'localhost:9990/pprof/heap?pause=10&sample_period=1024' >
> /tmp/prof This will collect heap growth for 10 seconds, with a
> sampling period of 1kB.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/ which runs a servlet with graphs of many common Java (and JDBC) metrics.  It's LGPL.